# How to define a function with 100 arguments

Tags: python, arguments

I am trying to define a function in Python. It should look like this:

```
def myfunction(Peter_1, Amy_1, Peter_2, Amy_2, Peter_3, Amy_3,....Peter_50,Amy_50):
    Peter_1 = 100
    Amy_1 = 20
    Peter_2 = 90
    Amy_2 = 4
    ...
    ...
```

I am using a small software writing in Python to do optimazation. The software is like that, after I define `myfunction` , I should write,

```
parameter1 = Parameter("Peter_1", (90,100),1)
parameter2 = Parameter("Amy_1", (15,25),1)
...
...
parameter99 = Parameter("Peter_50", (70,100),1)
parameter100 = Parameter("Amy_50", (15,25),1)
```

`Parameter` is the software defined function, the first argument of `Parameter` should be a string, and it has to be exactly the name I defined in `myfunction`. Then the software knows that the first parameter which need to be optimazed is `Peter_1`.
    I donot want to type all the 100 parameters, can anyone help me?

Comment: *"For some reason"* - what reason?! You should absolutely write the arguments as lists or tuples, e.g. `def myfunction(peters, amys)` or `def myfunction(*people)`. And there's little point defining parameters that are immediately reassigned inside the function.

Comment: Why not write them as lists? It's going to give you the same result... unless somehow you can convince us that it won't. If it's because your arguments aren't in a list from the calling context, you can pack them inside the function definition with *args, or vice-versa. What compelling argument would you have to do otherwise?

Comment: Yes, it is really stupid to type 100 arguments, agreed :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad code smell. You should wrap the arguments in an object. For example a dictionary.

Something like this:

```
def myfunction(people):
    for person_name in people.iterkeys():
        people[person_name] = 100

my_people = {}
my_people['Peter'] = 0
my_people['Simon'] = 0

myfunction(my_people)
print my_people
```

But my real concern is that you initialize the value in the function. Why not beforehand?

```
my_people = {}
my_people['Peter'] = 100
my_people['Simon'] = 90
```

That way you don't need the function.

Answer (score -1):

you can even use python *args syntax. For example something like this:

```
def foo(*args):
    for i in args:
        print(i)

foo(1,2)
foo(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
#output:
1
2
#second run:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7 
8
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, RvdK's answer works, but if you MUST write it the way you indicated in your question, then you should consider using the `exec()` function. That way you can write a small code inside your script that writes this function as a string for you. Then with `exec()` you can actually use the resulting string as an active part of the code.

Although, I would recommend that you use lists or tuples if that is a possibility.